# $f'(x)\neq0 \Rightarrow$ f is monotonic

Tags: calculus, derivatives, monotone-functions

let $\ f:[a,b] \rightarrow \Bbb{R} $, given that $f'(x) \neq 0$ can we conclude that $f$ is monotonic ?

Comment: Is $f'(x)$ continuous?

Comment: If it is continuous, then yes.

Comment: Consider a step function

Comment: Use Darboux theorem to conclude that derivative maintains a constant sign and hence the function is strictly monotone.

Comment: @kingW3 it is not known that $f'(x)$ is continuous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, assuming $f$ is differentiable for all $x \in [a,b]$ including the endpoints.

Actually, we can say it's *strictly* monotonic. There's two steps to proving this:

$(1)$ Note that if $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then $f$ is injective if and only if it's strictly monotonic. Proof: one direction is trivial, the other follows from the IVT. (in our case, we know $f$ is differentiable, so it is of course continuous).

$(2)$ If $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and $f'(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$, then $f$ is injective. Proof: suppose otherwise. Then there are $x,y \in [a,b]$ such that $\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x-y} = 0$. We derive a contradiction from the mean value theorem.

The comments are all incorrect and misleading. The continuity of the derivative is not needed here.